# PHP dynamic options in select inside html

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, drop-down-menu

I have categories and sub-category taken from API json file, the API returns category objects with "parent" attribute, main category objects have parent attribute equals to 0, and the sub-category objects have the parent attribute equals to the main categories id.

the code of main categories is `

```
<label for="Category"> Main Category</label>
                     <select id="category">
                    <?php foreach ($obj as $category):?>
                    <?php if($category->parent==0) : ?>
                     <option value=<?=$category->id?>><?=$category->name?></option>
                     <?php endif; ?>
                     <?php endforeach; ?>
                     </select>
```

`
$obj is equals to the json decode taken from api.
How I can write the code of the sub-categories? I want make options where subcategory->parent equals to the id of the selected category"category->id" chosen above

Answer (score 0):

So $obj is a list of all categories. Some are parents and some are children (subcategories)?

Is there a way to nest the categories on the API side so that it returns the children as a var on the parent object, or create a separate object for the children that you can access for each parent?

If those aren't an option, either format the categories prior to creating the select field so that you can more cleanly generate the children, or add a nested loop inside your current foreach that checks if a category is a child of the current category.

This is ugly and I haven't tested it, but you might be able to do something like this:

```
foreach ($obj as $category) {
    if ($category->parent==0) {
        echo "<option value='" . $category->id . "'>$category->name</option>"
        foreach ($obj as $subCategory) {
            if ($subCategory->parent != 0 && $subcategory->parent == $category->id) {
                echo "<option value='" . $subcategory->id . "'>$subcategory->name</option>"
            }
        }
    }
}
```